# How should i add a embeded document?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

I got this structure for my game Document

Game Document.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId( "51043d468ead0e0757000006" ),
  "active" : true,
  "created" : 1359232326,
  "difficulty" : 0,
  "map" : { "$ref" : "Map",
    "$id" : ObjectId( "5103c0228ead0e3764000000" ),
    "$db" : "mydb" },
  "mode" : "coop",
  "players" : [ 
    { "$ref" : "User",
      "$id" : ObjectId( "50d83abf038054b560000000" ),
      "$db" : "mydb" } ],
  "title" : "testgame" }
```

Now i want to add another player to this Game, this is what i've tried

```
  $user = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
    ->getRepository('FantasytdUserBundle:User')
    ->findById($userId);

  $db->createQueryBuilder()
    ->update()
    ->field('id')->equals($gameId)
    ->field('players')->push($user)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

Also

```
$user = array_pop($user->toArray());
```

No luck, all i get is

"zero-length keys are not allowed, did you use $ with double quotes?"

In my doctrine document the Players is defined to be a reference to User.

Comment: Why not $game->addPlayer() and flush?

Comment: Would't it then apply a new record then? I will try it out, seems like an easy way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK doctrine 2 can't push documents. You should prepare array:
Try something like this:

```
$user = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')
  ->getRepository('FantasytdUserBundle:User')
  ->findById($userId);

$user_data = array("$ref" => "User",
  "$id" : $user->getId(), // Or new \MongoId($userId)
  "$db" : "mydb");

$db->createQueryBuilder()
  ->update()
  ->field('id')->equals($gameId)
  ->field('players')->push($user_data)
  ->getQuery()
  ->execute();
```